# How to validate a Date format string in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, validation, flash, date, actionscript

We have this program in flex actionscript, which allows users to enter a format for dates. So when a date is displayed, it is displayed in the format the user enters.

e.g. User enters MM/DD/YYYY then March 11th, 2015 will be displayed 03/11/2015.

I want to make sure the user cannot enter an invalid format e.g MM/ddddd/YYYY.
How can I validate his input to contain only DD, MM YY, YYYY and delimiter characters.
All I found searching around, was how to validate the actual date against a given format, but not how to validate the format itself.

Kind Regards
Brecht

Comment: Why don't you using a list of valid formats and user can just check one ? Otherwise you can use [`RegExp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html).

Comment: How would you build up that regex?

Comment: You could also just have a dropdown showing valid formats - there shouldn't be that many.  Then create the date based on the selected format.